# How to close alertDialog from custom adapter

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to close the alertDialog on "Done" click from the soft keyboard after user enters input.I am using the dismiss() method but it doesn't work. I have to click out side the alertDialog box to escape it. Also this is being done from a custom adapter class not an activity.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ID);
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        final AlertDialog OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();


        //makes textView clickable
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                // put aler dialog box logic here
                builder.setTitle("Enter new chore");
                builder.setView(input);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                //checks if "Done" button on soft keyboard is clicked
                input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                            //what happens when "Done" is clicked
                            textView.setText(input.getText().toString());
                            OptionDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });



                builder.show();
            }
        });


        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: In TextView click listner you are creating new dialog whereas in editor listner you are dismissing another one

Answer (score 0):

try this  in onClick:

```
//comment this line
//final AlertDialog OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();

    //makes textView clickable
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //what happens when textView is clicked

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            AlertDialog OptionDialog = builder.create();
            // put aler dialog box logic here
            builder.setTitle("Enter new chore");
            builder.setView(input);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            //checks if "Done" button on soft keyboard is clicked
            input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                        //what happens when "Done" is clicked
                        textView.setText(input.getText().toString());
                        OptionDialog.dismiss();
                        //send true as the event has occured
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```